# How to trim a video stored in another sever via our node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

Trinning a video in Node.js is as easy as:

```
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath)

    ffmpeg('path_to_video_on_server/video.mp4')
      .setStartTime('00:00:03')
      .setDuration('10')
      .output('video_out.mp4')
      .on('end', function(err) {
        if(!err) { console.log('conversion Done') }
      })
      .on('error', err => console.log('error: ', err))
      .run()
```

But the issue is what if we store our videos in another server?

I mean now we have a path for the video like :

```
path_to_video_on_server/video.mp4
```

But what if we have this video in another server with this path:

```
www.example.com/path_to_video_on_server/video.mp4
```

Does replacing this new path work ?

If not how to trim a video stored in another sever via our node.js server ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to convert a file without having it somehow in your server memory.

The `ffmpeg` process needs to process the file data, otherwise you will not get any output.

There is a lot of options to solve it.

1. Download the file to your local server with `axios` or similar, then use ffmpeg as you used to.
2. Use external tool [like rclone](https://rclone.org/http/) to mount the remote files, then use ffmpeg as you used to.
3. Provide ffmpeg with a readStream of the file (can be done with `axios` too), that way your server will not have to store the entire original file.

It looks like you need only the first 10 seconds, so using a readStream is probably the best option, but also the most advanced. You need to learn how to use streams, and correctly handle streams errors.